# A long term puzzle, how to optimize multi-level loops in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have written a function in python to calculate Delta function in Gauss broadening, which involves 4-level loops. However, the efficiency is very low, about 10 times slower than using Fortran in a similar way.

```
def Delta_Gaussf(Nw, N_bd, N_kp, hw, eigv):
    Delta_Gauss = np.zeros((Nw,N_kp,N_bd,N_bd),dtype=float)
    for w1 in range(Nw):
        for k1 in range(N_kp):
            for i1 in range(N_bd):
                for j1 in range(N_bd):
                    if ( j1 >= i1 ):
                        Delta_Gauss[w1][k1][i1][j1] = np.exp(pow((eigv[k1][j1]-eigv[k1][i1]-hw[w1])/width,2))
    return Delta_Gauss
```

I have removed some constants to make it looks simpler.

Could any one help me to optimize this script to increase efficiency?

Comment: You may want to look at [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/); it includes native bindings for large operations involving vectors.

Comment: It's very difficult to figure out the higher-order operation you're really trying to accomplish here, i.e. it looks like this code implements some element-level form of, say, matrix multiplication or some such linear algebra operation. You'll get much better answers if you could explain the higher-order operation(s) you're really doing here.

Comment: What is your bottleneck? CPU? RAM?

Comment: Also, this question is a bit on the border, but it *might* be a bit more fitting over on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) since it *does* work in its current form.

Comment: you could use `concurrent.futures` and use async compute to divide your problem into subproblems if thats possilbe which from looking at it, it probably is. also without the complete fortran and python code we couldnt possibly tell you where the bottleneck is

Comment: btw, `numpy` is itself written, at least partially, in Fortran, so if you can use it properly to vectorize this problem, it should definitely be competitive in terms of performance (whether it's better or worse in the end depends on a number of other factors)

Comment: @Matt_G, it's time

Comment: @scnerd Hmm, it does not involve multiplication, but many indexes. So it looks like complicated

Comment: I learned it is a good idea to vectorize this problem. I used a lot of Fortran, which deeply affects my coding style, sigh

Comment: @zython there are no additional code. the hw = linspace(0., 1.0, endpoint=False, Nw) with Nw e.g., 2000; eigv = np.zeros(N_kp, N_bd) with N_kp e.g., 8000, N_bd e.g. 60

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Simply compile it

To get the best performance I recommend Numba (easy usage, good performance). Alternatively Cython may be a good idea, but with a bit more changes to your code.

You actually got everything right and implemented a easy to understand (for a human and most important for a compiler) solution.

**There are basically two ways to gain performance**

1. Vectorize the code as @scnerd showed. This is usually a bit slower and more complex than simply compile a quite simple code, that only uses some for loops. **Don't** vectorize your code and than use a compiler. From a simple looping aproach this is usually some work to do and leads to a slower and more complex result. The advantage of this process is that you only need numpy, which is a standard dependency in nearly every Python project that deals with some numerical calculations.
2. Compile the code. If you have already a solution with a few loops and no other, or only a few non numpy functions involved this is often the simplest and fastest solution.

**A solution using Numba**

You do not have to change much, I changed the pow function to np.power and some slight changes to the way arrays accessed in numpy (this isn't really necessary).

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

#performance-debug info
import llvmlite.binding as llvm
llvm.set_option('', '--debug-only=loop-vectorize')

@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def Delta_Gaussf_nb(Nw, N_bd, N_kp, hw, width,eigv):
    Delta_Gauss = np.zeros((Nw,N_kp,N_bd,N_bd),dtype=float)
    for w1 in range(Nw):
        for k1 in range(N_kp):
            for i1 in range(N_bd):
                for j1 in range(N_bd):
                    if ( j1 >= i1 ):
                        Delta_Gauss[w1,k1,i1,j1] = np.exp(np.power((eigv[k1,j1]-eigv[k1,i1]-hw[w1])/width,2))
    return Delta_Gauss
```

Due to the 'if' the SIMD-vectorization fails. In the next step we can remove it (maybe a call outside the njited function to `np.triu(Delta_Gauss)` will be necessary). I also parallelized the function.

```
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def Delta_Gaussf_1(Nw, N_bd, N_kp, hw, width,eigv):
    Delta_Gauss = np.zeros((Nw,N_kp,N_bd,N_bd),dtype=np.float64)
    for w1 in nb.prange(Nw):
        for k1 in range(N_kp):
            for i1 in range(N_bd):
                for j1 in range(N_bd):
                    Delta_Gauss[w1,k1,i1,j1] = np.exp(np.power((eigv[k1,j1]-eigv[k1,i1]-hw[w1])/width,2))
    return Delta_Gauss
```

**Performance**

```
Nw = 20
N_bd = 20
N_kp = 20
width=20
hw = np.linspace(0., 1.0, Nw) 
eigv = np.zeros((N_kp, N_bd),dtype=np.float) 

Your version:           0.5s
first_compiled version: 1.37ms
parallel version:       0.55ms
```

These easy optimizations lead to about 1000x speedup.

Comment: Thanks a lot for introducing numba. I like it since it make the code readable and easy to maintain

Comment: Excellent solution, I wish I'd tried the easy solution first. Thanks for the article on using `numba` effectively

Comment: @max9111  With 'nb.njit(fastmath=True)', the efficiency gain is massive. But further adding the 'parallel=True' not necessarily help the 'fastmath=True'. Also, I don't understand why "Due to the 'if' the SIMD-vectorization fails". As I see, I can keep 'if', which also leads to further gain in efficiency

Comment: N_kp = 50, N_bd = 58.  Without numba, t = 680s, with numba (only fastmath), t = 4.5 s, with numba (fastmath+parallel), t=5.8s

Comment: Take a look at https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/faq.html. Adding  import llvmlite.binding as llvm
llvm.set_option('', '--debug-only=loop-vectorize') should show if vectorization works. Do you have Intel SVML installed? Which processor and RAM do you have (the optimizations I suggested are on a Core i7 4th gen Quadcore with Dual-Channel DDR3 RAM. Ad parallelization: I expect that this function runs in a memory bottleneck quite soon. The fastmath-speedup is that massive because the np.power(value,2) is simplified to a much simpler value*value.

Comment: Wich Numba Version do you use, I did this on 0.39dev. There has been serveral improvements in parallelization. In general fastmath does some  non safe optimizations (algebraically the result stays the same, but numerical precision may vary) eg. the division by a constant can also be simplified to a multiplication by (1/constant). The usually more costly division has to be computed only once.

Comment: Yes, you are write. I do have encountered the memory problem, because the array size would be kind of 2000*1000*58*58 or even a little bit larger

Comment: @max9111, Oops, I used the 0.36 dev, now I updated to the 0.38 dev

Answer (score 5):

BLUF: Using Numpy's full functionality, plus another neat module, you can get the Python code down over 100x faster than this raw for-loop code. Using @max9111's answer, however, you can get even faster with much cleaner code and less work.

The resulting code looks nothing like the original, so I'll do the optimization one step at a time so that the process and final code make sense. Essentially, we're going to use a lot of [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) in order to get Numpy to perform the looping under the hood (which is always faster than looping in Python). The result computes the full square of results, which means we're necessarily duplicating some work since the result is symmetrical, but it's easier, and honestly probably faster, to do this work in high-performance ways than to have an `if` at the deepest level of looping in order to avoid the computation. This might be avoidable in Fortran, but probably not in Python. If you want the result to be identical to your provided source, we'll need to take the [upper triangle](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html) of the result of my code below (which I do in the sample code below... feel free to remove the `triu` call in actual production, it's not necessary).

First, we'll notice a few things. The main equation has a denominator that performs `np.sqrt`, but the content of that computation doesn't change at any iteration of the loop, so we'll compute it once and re-use the result. This turns out to be minor, but we'll do it anyway. Next, the main function of the inner two loops is to perform `eigv[k1][j1] - eigv[k1][i1]`, which is quite easy to vectorize. If `eigv` is a matrix, then `eigv[k1] - eigv[k1].T` produces a matrix where `result[i1, j1] = eigv[k1][j1] - eigv[k1][i1]`. This allows us to entirely remove the innermost two loops:

```
def mine_Delta_Gaussf(Nw, N_bd, N_kp, hw, width, eigv):
    Delta_Gauss = np.zeros((Nw, N_kp, N_bd, N_bd), dtype=float)
    denom = np.sqrt(2.0 * np.pi) * width
    eigv = np.matrix(eigv)
    for w1 in range(Nw):
        for k1 in range(N_kp):
            this_eigv = (eigv[k1] - eigv[k1].T - hw[w1])
            v = np.power(this_eigv / width, 2)
            Delta_Gauss[w1, k1, :, :] = np.exp(-0.5 * v) / denom

    # Take the upper triangle to make the result exactly equal to the original code
    return np.triu(Delta_Gauss)
```

Well, now that we're on the broadcasting bandwagon, it really seems like the remaining two loops should be possible to remove in the same way. As it happens, it is easy! The only thing we need `k1` for is to get the row out of `eigv` that we're trying to pairwise-subtract... so why not do this to all rows at the same time? We're currently basically subtracting matrices of shapes `(1, B) - (B, 1)` for each of `N` rows in `eigv` (where `B` is is `N_bd`). We can abuse broadcasting to do this for all rows of `eigv` simultaneously by subtracting matrices of shapes `(N, 1, B) - (N, B, 1)` (where `N` is `N_kp`):

```
def mine_Delta_Gaussf(Nw, N_bd, N_kp, hw, width, eigv):
    Delta_Gauss = np.zeros((Nw, N_kp, N_bd, N_bd), dtype=float)
    denom = np.sqrt(2.0 * np.pi) * width
    for w1 in range(Nw):
        this_eigv = np.expand_dims(eigv, 1) - np.expand_dims(eigv, 2) - hw[w1]
        v = np.power(this_eigv / width, 2)
        Delta_Gauss[w1, :, :, :] = np.exp(-0.5 * v) / denom
    return np.triu(Delta_Gauss)
```

The next step should be clear now. We're only using `w1` to index `hw`, so let's do some more broadcasting to make `numpy` do the looping instead. We're currently subtracting a scalar value from a matrix of shape `(N, B, B)`, so to get the resulting matrix for each of the `W` values in `hw`, we need to perform subtraction on matrices of the shapes `(1, N, B, B) - (W, 1, 1, 1)` and `numpy` will broadcast everything to produce a matrix of the shape `(W, N, B, B)`:

```
def Delta_Gaussf(hw, width, eigv):
    eigv_sub = np.expand_dims(eigv, 1) - np.expand_dims(eigv, 2)
    w_sub = np.expand_dims(eigv_sub, 0) - np.reshape(hw, (0, 1, 1, 1))
    v = np.power(w_sub / width, 2)
    denom = np.sqrt(2.0 * np.pi) * width
    Delta_Gauss = np.exp(-0.5 * v) / denom
    return np.triu(Delta_Gauss)
```

On my example data, this code is ~100x faster (~900ms to ~10ms). Your mileage might vary.

But wait! There's more! Since our code is all numeric/numpy/python, we can use another handy module called [`numba`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jit.html) to compile this function into an equivalent one with higher performance. Under the hood, it's basically reading what functions we're calling and converting the function into C-types and C-calls to remove the Python function call overhead. It's doing more than that, but that gives the jist of where we're going to gain benefit. To gain this benefit is trivial in this case:

```
import numba

@numba.jit
def Delta_Gaussf(hw, width, eigv):
    eigv_sub = np.expand_dims(eigv, 1) - np.expand_dims(eigv, 2)
    w_sub = np.expand_dims(eigv_sub, 0) - np.reshape(hw, (0, 1, 1, 1))
    v = np.power(w_sub / width, 2)
    denom = np.sqrt(2.0 * np.pi) * width
    Delta_Gauss = np.exp(-0.5 * v) / denom
    return np.triu(Delta_Gauss)
```

The resulting function is down to about ~7ms on my sample data, down from ~10ms, just by adding that decorator. Pretty nice for no effort.

---

EDIT: @max9111 gave a better answer that points out that `numba` works much better with the loop syntax than with `numpy` broadcasting code. With almost no work besides the removal of the inner `if` statement, he shows that `numba.jit` can be made to get the almost original code even faster. The result is much cleaner, in that you still have just the single innermost equation that shows what each value is, and you don't have to follow the magical broadcasting used above. I highly recommend using his answer.

---

Conclusion

For my given sample data (Nw = 20, N_bd = 20, N_kp = 20), my final runtimes are the following (I've included timings on the same computer for @max9111's solution, first without using parallel execution and then with it on my 2-core VM):

```
Original code:               ~900 ms
Fortran estimate:            ~90 ms (based on OP saying it was ~10x faster)
Final numpy code:            ~10 ms
Final code with numba.jit:   ~7 ms
max9111's solution (serial): ~4ms
max9111 (parallel 2-core):   ~3ms

Overall vectorized speedup: ~130x
max9111's numba speedup: ~300x (potentially more with more cores)
```

I don't know how fast exactly your Fortran code is, but it looks like proper usage of `numpy` allows you to easily beat it by an order of magnitude, and @max9111's `numba` solution gives you potentially another order of magnitude.

Comment: Wow, that is one thorough response

Comment: @RishiG probably will end up being under-appreciated for being too wordy and on not that broadly applicable of a question, but it was fun to work on anyway.

Comment: yeah, I liked it anyway

Comment: Normally a code with simple for loops performs better when using Numba. Have you measured that? Using Intel SVML is also recommendable, maybe also fastmath=True. https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/performance-tips.html And last but not least parallelization can be enabled too.

Comment: Good suggestions, I'll give those a shot when I get a chance. I'd be a bit surprised if numba on the for loops beat numba on the vectorized version, but it's certainly worth a shot.

Comment: In the vectorized approach you are creating temporary arrays and calling quite some functions which are based on loops (have a look on the numpy source code or the llvm IR-Code). All this things have to be optimized away, to get the best performance. At the end the compiler has to solve a quite more complicated problem and usually don't get the best performance out of it. C and Fortran are not built in the way they are built to torture folks. The syntax makes it simply easier for a compiler to generate efficient code and makes the compiler itself simpler.

Comment: @scnerd Thanks a lot, it helps me a lot how to improve my python code.

Comment: I have (4C/8T). (Numba 0.39 dev + IntelSVML). There has been some performance improvements when using paralleliziation in 0.38. The most intensive computation is calculating exp. (np.power(value,2) is simplified to the faster value*value). (exp, sin,cos,...) See a substancial speedup on SIMD-vectorized loops if IntelSVML is installed. https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/performance-tips.html

Also make sure that hw and eigv are aligned and contiguous.