# Numpy: populating arrays to vectorize nested summations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, vectorization

I would like to vectorize nested sums in Python, in order to speed up the process. At the moment I have nested for loops.

```
    for ja in np.arange(0,Na):
        for jb in np.arange(0,Nb):
            for ma in np.arange(-ja,ja+1):
            ...
```

The end result is the sum across 2x2 matrices, each with entries dependent on the values of ja,jb,ma,mb.
The matrices look like:

```
[[f11(ja,jb,ma,mb),f12(ja,jb,ma,mb)],
 [f21(ja,jb,ma,mb),f22(ja,jb,ma,mb)]]
```

where fij are functions. The functions can be applied to arrays as they will  work element by element (expoenetials, square roots, trig functions etc...). I can create arrays like:

```
ja=[0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
jb=[0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3]
```

By using

```
range_a = np.arange(0,Na/2+1)
range_b = np.arange(0,Nb/2+1)
ja = np.tile(a_range,Nb/2+1)
jb = np.repeat(b_range,Na/2+1)
```

But my trouble is to create arrays, such that for each value in the above j we have the m structure (from -j to j):

```
ma=[0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,1,1,1,-2,-2,-2,...]
mb=[0,-1,0,1,-2,-1,0,1,2,...]
```

I am having trouble making those m arrays though! each time a -j,..,j structure repeats it has a different length, so I cannot use functions like `numpy.tile` and `numpy.repeat`. So, any ideas on how to do this?

My further intentions might be relevant: I hope to be able to pad them with zeros and construct 2*length matrices, so that only one entry is populated (I need 4 matrices for each vector, total of 4 vectors). Then I can apply the functions to and add these upp. To calculate the summation across the 2*2 matrices I will dot product with a matrix that is length*4 in shape. The result is 2*2. Perhaps a better strategy exists? I thought this might have occurred before, as it has a common application in physics (trace over a density operator) but I have not found it.

Comment: 1) Use iterators (xrange in Python 2 or range in Python 3).  2) There is absolutely no problem in looping as much as you wan't in Cython or Numba eg. https://stackoverflow.com/q/50220638/4045774 If an efficient solution in C or Fortran seems straight forward, don't think around the corner if there is no obvious way to vectorize it. 3) Write down some relevant example (including timings, input data, usually som random data).